# Minimum MySQL version requirement for 'unix_timestamp'

Tags: mysql

I am using 'unix_timestamp' in my db queries and I was wondering, if anybody knows the minimum MySQL version requirement for this command to work. It would be fine, if I could give the users of my product a minimum requirement for the MySQL version as well.

So far, I am quite certain that it works with MySQL 5.0 and later.

Comment: What's the most minimum version you can find?

Comment: Why not just put your minimum to 5.0 then? Might as well encourage upgrading MySQL versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a corresponding changelog, but I found [a bugreport concerning 4.0.22 and `unix_timestamp`](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9191), so 4.0.22 (or 4.0) as minimum requirement seems fine to me.

All versions below are negligible. [4.0 was released in March 2003 and its support ended in early 2007.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Versions) So even running this version would be careless. Not to mention even older versions.

Comment: The MySQL code is used in the CMS Joomla!, which has a min req of MySQL 5.0.4 for Joomla! 2.5 anyway. Thus, I was mainly worried that there might be a MySQL 5.x versions that does not support this command. I guess that if it was already introduced in 4.0.x, it is most likely represented as stable in all 5.x versions.